# Autoprefixer is not working on Sublime text 3, showing error

Tags: sublimetext3, autoprefixer

In sublime text 3, i tried to install Autofrefixer but didn't work.  I have tried like this...

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> > *install package* > *Autoprefixer* > *Autoprefix css*

Then a popup came out and showing me this message:

> Autoprfixer couldn't find Node.js. Make sure it's in your $PATH by running `node-v` in your command line.

Here a image...
[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygE0s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `node -v` in terminal. It should display message that 
The

> program 'node' is currently not installed.

So type in terminal

```
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

And try running prefix again. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. after install node.js in my pc problem has been solved..
@Retro